# Vscode tasks.json g++: error: src\*.cpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to compile all files in a certain directory, but g++ is giving an error.
It says "invalid argument". I am using Windows 11. Here is my directory structure

[image: The structure]

Here is my tasks.json file -

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-c",
                "${fileDirname}\\*.cpp",
                //"-g",
                //"-Wall",
                //"-m64",
                //"-I",
                //"include",
                //"-I",
                //"C:\\SDL2-w64\\include",
                //"-o",
                //"bin\\debug\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                //"-l",
                //"C:\\SDL2-w64\\lib",
                //"-lmingw32",
                //"-lSDL2main",
                //"-lSDL2",
                //"-lSDL_image",
                //"&&",
                //"start",
                //"bin\\release\\main"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

For any further details comment it. ANY help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is, main.cpp is in there, did u not see the dir structure?

Comment: oh ok..........

Comment: Do you really have comments in your JSON file? I think it is not allowed to put comments in JSON.

Comment: Just ignore the comments.

Comment: [Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+code+c%2B%2B+multiple+source+files+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this issue for myself for the past few hours. I found that if you have any spaces in your filepath, which causes the entire path to be surrounded by quotes, including the `*.cpp` part, which is then not recognized properly. Removing spaces from the filepath, or, if you can find a way to do:
`"C:/whatever/your/filepath/is/"*.cpp`
where the quotes do not include the `*.cpp` part.

`"C:/whatever/your/filepath/is/"*.cpp` - works

`"C:/whatever/your/filepath/is/*.cpp"` - does not work

This is probably an issue that MinGW needs to fix.

Comment: MinGW doesn't need to fix anything. It's the VSC issue that it adds the quotes.

Comment: No, it is indeed a MinGW issue. VSC adds the quotes only on filepaths which contain spaces, which is necessary behavior for commands. Without the quotes and it's no longer a contiguous filepath. Perhaps VSC needs to add an exception to exclude recursive and file extensions from quotes, but this issue is only present in MinGW, to my knowledge.

Comment: I can't reproduce, for me `*` works even in quotes (for MSYS2 MinGW at least). This is an interesting topic. On Linux, quotes disabling `*` expansion is intended (since on Linux the shell does the expansion, and can enforce the uniform behavior for all apps). But on Windows, each individual app is responsible for the expanding `*`, but it seems that the apps don't normally see the quotes given to them, so they have to choice but to process `*` even in quotes (or never process it). It also seems that MinGW embeds the `*` expansion into every app it produces, while MSVC doesn't.

Comment: I only tested in Wine so far, I'll try in a VM too...